# Interpolating special characters (\t, \n, \r etc.) at runtime in C#

Tags: c#

The C# compiler interpolates special character literals like \t for tab, \n for newline etc. But is there a built-in C# or .Net function that can interpolate them at runtime?

For example, at runtime I read a configuration for a text-delimited file format, maybe something like this:

```
Delimiter: \t
LineEnding: \r\n
```

Right now the only thing I can think of doing is reading in the string and then performing a Replace() with compiler-interpolated strings:

```
Delimiter = Delimiter.Replace(@"\n", "\n").Replace(@"\r", "\r");
```

Comment: What's wrong with the way you're doing it?

Comment: I figured it would be dumb to write my own utility function and carry it around everywhere if there was something built-in. Something that would handle the whole set (\0, \a, \b, \f, \n, \r, \t, \u, \U, \x, \v). It's one of those "SURELY there's gotta be something built-in for this" questions

Comment: This comes up quite a lot - there should be a standard library for this, non?

Comment: Sort of related: string interpolation in the mono C# compiler: http://tirania.org/blog/archive/2009/Dec-20.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try `Regex.Unescape` which possible satisfies all your requirements.

```
foreach (var special in new string[] { @"\n", @"\t", @"\r\n" })
{
    Console.WriteLine("|{0}|", special);
    Console.WriteLine("|{0}|", Regex.Unescape(special));
    Console.WriteLine("----------------------"); 
}
```

From MSDN:

> It replaces the representation of
>   unprintable characters with the
>   characters themselves. For example, it
>   replaces \a with \x07. The character
>   representations it replaces are \a,
>   \b, \e, \n, \r, \f, \t, and \v.